# AWS Lex and Slack integration not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

Bot is working fine in Lex console, but I am not getting any response via Slack.

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/slack-bot-association.html for Slack integration

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it stopped working very recently. Check out this form post here by AWS.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=959951